# copy an xml file then save it

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

the source file: http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

I want to save as this file as "eurofxref-daily-yesterday.xml" under the wwwroot directory..

using c#..
how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WebRequestNResponseMDB12012005232323PM/WebRequestNResponseMDB.aspx

you can fetch the file and then read the data into memory then write it out to a fil on your server.